# The command `npx create-react-app my-app` does not create an application file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to install `create-react-app`. I'm using the command: `npx create-react-app my-app`. I can see the following information in the console:

**`Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes. Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template ... added 1374 packages in 4m 163 packages are looking for funding run npm fund for details`**

and nothing is happening.

`node` and `npm` are the newest

In the folder I just created, I can only see `node-modules, package, package-lock`. I don't have a file `src`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with these steps :

1. npm rm -g create-react-app
2. npm install -g create-react-app
3. npx create-react-app my-app

**Update**

1. install yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)
2. install CRA with yarn!

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: You should install CRA with other package manager. Try yarn create react-app my-app!

Comment: @Umbro hello I edit my solution. Try it and tell me if it works!

Comment: I used `yarn`. I see still only 3 files `node_modules, package, yarn_lock` and in terminal I see list of dependencies and message `Done in 461.69s.` nothing else happens